# Как правильно написать в php условие - if, else?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Нужно в php написать следующее условие:
Если присутствует div class="A", то показывать "1111". Если он отсутствует, то показывать "2222".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (stripos($your_string, 'div class="A"') !== false) {
    // .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
если (условие) {
    делаем это
} если нет, тогда {
    делаем это
}

if (condition) {
    # do this
} else {
    # do this
}
```

А дальше выставляйте свои условия. Надо понять, как вы хотите отловить div class="A" и где оно присутствует у вас.